# EC2+nginx+django+gunicorn+letsencrypt ssl -> TIMED OUT

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I've been struggling for a few hours now and went through lots of similar questions on SE.
However, I couldn't manage to fix my probelm .

To answer the obvious questions:

- there's no firewall on my ec2 (ubuntu) instance running
- the 443 port is open for in/outbound
- ssl files created with `sudo certbot certonly --standalone`
- non-encrypted requests work fine
- I've setup my domain’s A-Record to point to the public DNS of my EC2 instance. There are no options for Namespace records though.
- Yes indeed, I'm an idiot

I haven't touched the nginx.conf-file besides adding:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

My nginx-conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf (with symbolic link in ...../sites-enabled/myapp.conf):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 default ssl;   

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem;

        server_name mydomain;

        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/ubuntu/MYAPP/static/;
        }

        location /data/ {
                autoindex off;
                alias /home/ubuntu/MYAPP/data/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/MYAPP/app.sock;
        }
}
```

In my APPS's settings.py I've added:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
  'localhost',
  '127.0.0.1',
  'mywebsite.com']
```

For now, I've commented out the following

```
#SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
#SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Issuing `nc -vz localhost 443` gives `Connection to localhost 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!`

`netstat -ntlp` gives

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

However, `curl -v localhost:443` results in

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.71.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 15:14:04 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 264
< Connection: close
< 
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

And trying to access my domain via https://... results in a time-out.

EDIT: As Steffen points out, my curl command was wrong. Here's the right one

```
curl -v https://localhost:443
```

gving rise to

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=mydomain.com
*  start date: Jan  8 10:37:06 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Apr  8 10:37:06 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match localhost
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Now,
/var/log/nginx/error.log
doesn't show any errors.

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log
```

doesn't show any request when I try to open via https in my browser.
With just http, the requests are logged.
So its seems like the request don't even arrive at nginx, right?

I've never used nginx (or anything server/backend-related really) before and I'm absolutely clueless.

EDIT2: Do I need an elastic ip for this to work?
Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `curl -v https://localhost:443` (or simply `https://localhost` w/o port) instead of `curl -v localhost:443`, i.e. use HTTPS and not HTTP.

Comment: you're using a certificate issued to domain `mydomain.com`, yet you're accessing it with `localhost`. Try `curl -v --insecure https://localhost`.